# generating barcode as an image, and embed it to an rdlc

Tags: .net, barcode, rdlc

First, I'd like to describe my current situation.
I have an RDLC whose data is taken from a dataset "ds" using Stored Procedure "sp". Lets say that from "ds" I can get a field of type String called "bar_code", and in turn can be used in a placeholder combined with a 3of9 font to generate the barcode.

Now, I'd like to obtain the same result, but using another method which, given a string, will return an image of barcode in BMP or JPEG format. This method is already described at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-generate-barcodes-using-c/173.

My question : is it possible to write the method in the ReportViewer code behind (.aspx.cs) ?
If it is possible, how can I pass that "bar_code" into this method and then embed the result (the JPEG or BMP) into the RDLC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article you refer to has info about how to generate the barcode from an aspx.

One tiny part is missing: you use that "BarcodeGenerator.aspx?data=11111111" link as the 'src' of an `<img>` node in your html.

By the way: "gif" is better than "jpg" in this case: jpg can cause unwanted artifacts, making the barcode difficult to scan. "bmp" is usually too big.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer.
We can obtain the value that we want to be converted into image from the Stored Procedure by calling the DataSetTableAdapter from the code-behind, fill it with any required parameters, and then store the result in a DataTable.
After that, we loop through each row and pass the obtained value into the method for generating BMP barcode. The key is we must store this BMP in a column with System.Byte[] type, so we add a new column in our DataTable with that type. It won't work if we store it in System.Object.
Use MemoryStream to save the image into Byte[] :

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image_result.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

Then, set our RDLC DataSource into using that new DataTable and add a placeholder by type of Image in our RDLC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Barcode.dll [barcode component](http://www.limilabs.com/barcode) it supports RDLC reports (web and windows).

You just need to one simple method to RDLC code tab:

1. Open Report.rdlc in design mode, select "Properties" from the context menu on grey field:
   a. Take a look at "References" tab, Barcode.dll is referenced there, and BarcodeFactory is instantiated.
   b. Note that Barcode.dll must be registered in GAC - installer does that.
   c. Take a look at "Code" tab, GetBarcode128 method is defined there.
2. Take a look at Image control below "ID" text, note its properties:
   MimeType    "image/png"
   Source      "DataBase"
   Value       "=Code.GetBarcode128(Fields!Name.Value)"

Download package includes RDLC samples.

Comment: Hi Pawel Lesnikowski, I liked the website information and component support. Can we do Code.GetBarcodeEAN(Fields!Name.Value) and Code.GetBarcode38(Fields!Name.Value) in the same style?

Comment: Yes you can, you can easy create similar methods to GetBarcode128 that use other symbology - it would be simple copy&paste operation

Answer (score 0):

you can store the image in a byte[] field in your dataset and display that using an image control on the rdlc report

the other option would be create a new parameter and pass it in that way.

if its going into the page header of footer there are other issues to deal with. then you need to store it in a textbox using =Convert.ToBase64String(First(Fields!BarcodeImage.Value, "DataSet Name")) and then display it in the image using Convert.FromBase64String(ReportItems!NameOfYourTextBox.Value)

also look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2434/Drawing-Barcodes-in-Windows-Part-1-Code-39 on how to generate an image.

i have used this and returned the image as a stream and put that stream into my byte[] column (or passed as parameter) to print on report